# Deleting data in the database after doing an integration test

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to do an integration test writing some data in the database and I need to delete all these data from the database when the integration test finish.

I’m using:

1. Entity Framework 6.1.3.
2. Sql Server 2014 (localDB)

I’ve tried to do it using nested transactions using:

1. DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction() but it doesn't work
2. TransactionScope but it doesn’t work too

I’ve been scratching my head against the table two days in a row because I’m trying to avoid:

1. deleting and creating the database every time I run an integration test
2. deleting manually the data the integration test wrote.

I'm doing this integration test against the database because it involves a database transaction.

Can someone give me an idea about how to solve this?

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: @NickBailey did you read the beginning of the post?

Comment: I personally like `Respawn` by Jimmy Bogard (of Automapper fame) - see here: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/02/19/reliable-database-tests-with-respawn/

Comment: Commit the data to your database, run your test, then delete data if you need to. If you're not doing this, it's not realistic.

Comment: Doesn't work? Do you get an error? data not deleted?

Comment: Well obviously not. Sheesh.

Comment: I solved the problem using TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled). I'm using context.SaveChangesAsync() and I was using the parameterless ctor of TransactionScope(). That's why it wasn't working